# Is it possible to run a CodedUI test with the screen locked?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, user-interface

I wrote a auto UI test project (using Coded UI framework) and deployed it on a server.
I want to schedule the testing task, to run every night say 12:00.

My problem is when the server is locked (the user is still logged on), it cannot run successfully and the error message is:

> Automation engine is unable to playback the test because it is not
>   able to interact with the desktop.  This could happen if the computer
>   running the test is locked or it’s remote session window is minimized.

Is there any way I can schedule the Coded UI test on the server too always run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general it is not possible to run a UI test if the desktop is locked, a user is not logged in, if there is a screen saver running, etc.  The workarounds I've seen to avoid these problems are to disable the screen saver and [set auto-logon for the computer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963905) so that there is always a user logged in. To ensure the machine is ready for testing, you can reboot it; a few minutes later, it should be sitting at an unlocked screen with a logged in test user.

Note that you should only do this for a test client machine and **not a server that is intended to be used for sensitive, secure, or critical tasks**.